# How to use xpath to select elements by xsd type in instance document?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xsd

For example:
My xsd is:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="Zoo">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element ref="Animal"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element abstract="true" name="Animal"/>
    <xs:element name="Tiger" substitutionGroup="Animal" type="Tiger"/>
    <xs:element name="Wolf" substitutionGroup="Animal" type="Wolf"/>
    <xs:complexType name="Animal">
        <xs:attribute name="name"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="Tiger">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="Animal"/>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="Wolf">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="Animal"/>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

My instance document is:

```
<Zoo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Zoo.xsd">
    <Tiger name="001"/>
    <Wolf name="002"/>
    <Wolf name="003"/>
</Zoo>
```

How to use xpath to select all elements whose complex type is Animal?
Can xpath be able to use xsd meta information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a schema-aware processor (like Saxon 9 EE or Altova XMLSpy/Raptor) you can use `//element(*, Animal)` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#doc-xpath31-ElementTest) to select all elements with that type `Animal`, a stylesheet would look like

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:import-schema schema-location="Zoo.xsd"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy-of select="//element(*, Animal)"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It works on oxygen xml editor which xpath builder choose XPath 3.0SA, but your xslt return empty.

Comment: Make sure you configure the transformation scenario to use Saxon EE and to enable schema based validation.

Comment: I have configured the transformation scenario to use Saxon EE, but what's the meaning of "enable schema based validation"? (where to configure transformation scenario to make it aware xml schema?) In oxygen xml editor, I can validate zoo.xml by clicking button "Validate with..." .

Comment: Sorry, I have a more question about this problem. Do you know the schema-aware XPath expression (like: //element(*, Animal)) is a new one in XPath 3.1 specification or it is just a feature of Saxon 9 EE? Why I can't use it in XPath 1.0/2.0/3.0 (For example: This expression doesn't work on Oxygen XML Editor's XPath builder which choose XPath 1.0/2.0/3.0, only XPath 3.0 SA can work.)

Comment: Schema aware processing was introduced in XSLT/XPath 2.0, the specs are all online, see https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-element-test. But the processor needs to support it, in case of Saxon I think schema-aware processing has always been a feature of the EE edition or earlier the SA (schema-aware) edition (when there were only two editons, the Basic and the SA one). As the oXygen support on whether or how you can use schema-aware XPath 2.0 in oXygen, I am sure they can tell if their docs don't have enough information.

Comment: As for doing XSLT/XPath 1.0 with schema information, Microsoft has never updated its XSLT/XPath 1.0 implementation to implement anything of XSLT/XPath 2 or 3 but they introduced some proprietary extension functions in MSXML 4/5/6, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256457.aspx for an example.